# How to remove Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5

Tags: .net-6.0

I am trying to remove the preview versions of dot net 6.

if I run dotnet --info i see

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.100
 Commit:    9e8b04bbff

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22000
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.0
  Commit:  4822e3c3aa

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21501.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

When I run dotnet-core-uninstall.exe list I see

```
This tool cannot uninstall versions of the runtime or SDK that are 
    - SDKs installed using Visual Studio 2019 Update 3 or later.
    - SDKs and runtimes installed via zip/scripts.
    - Runtimes installed with SDKs (these should be removed by removing that SDK).
The versions that can be uninstalled with this tool are:

.NET Core SDKs:
  6.0.100  x64    [Used by Visual Studio. Specify individually or use —-force to remove]

.NET Core Runtimes:

ASP.NET Core Runtimes:

.NET Core Runtime & Hosting Bundles:
```

It does not show the preview versions, so how do I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the folder directly from C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\ which sems to do the trick